# Android Media Recorder causes device to lock after long periods of recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I'm currently using the Android Media Recorder to capture video from the camera prior to streaming it.

I'm finding that if I continuously record content for long periods of time 45 minutes + the device eventually locks up and the following error is written to the logs continuously

> 03-12 12:09:26.430: E/Camera2-StreamingProcessor(128):
>   onFrameAvailable: Camera 0: No free recording buffers, dropping frame

Eventually the application will display the 'stopped responding dialog' and I can kill the app.

It appears that the length of time that this issue takes to occur is dependent on the resolution and quality I record at and the length of time and number of recording sessions I have done previously. Rebooting the device does improve the situation, I once got 1 hour and 10 minutes after a reboot at 720p.

Are there known limitations on Android when it comes to recording for long period of times?

I believe that the Camera application on the device does impose recording limits is this correct?

Does anyone know of any solutions for the error I am seeing above?